# Apache on xampp shut down unexpectedly

Tags: apache

I'm running Xampp v3.3.0 on windows 10, I recently had a reset and reinstall of my PC and also my xampp. Now, anytime I try to start the appache service, I get this...

```
    03:35:40  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
    03:35:40  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, 
    missing dependencies, 
    03:35:40  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a 
    shutdown by another method.
    03:35:40  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error 
    logs and check
    03:35:40  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    03:35:40  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post 
    this
    03:35:40  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I've gotten answers that involve changing port 80 and others, done that and restarted my PC and apache to no avail..It still won't start

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Run cmd as an administrator
- Navigate to xampp/apache/bin
- Type httpd -t

That will check the validity of your apache config file.